# Why does an expensive test run slower under googletest than standalone?

Tags: c++, performance, unit-testing, googletest

In a recent project, I had one test case that could serve as a stress test, and I ended up deciding to record it in the unit test sources though without compiling it in by default.  What I'm thinking is that if I decide to make some tweaks to algorithms or implementation in the future, then that case could be an informal check on how those tweaks affect performance.

However, when I enabled the test as part of the test suite, I was surprised to find it took several times longer to run that calculation than it did with a simple standalone driver program which runs essentially the same calculation:

```
daniel@frobnitz:~/git/groebner-zx/builddir$ time ./groebner < /tmp/groebner_test_case.txt 
< x^20 + 5 x^17 + 3 x^16 + 9 x^10 - 3 x^7 - x^5, 3 x^19 + x^17 + 4 x^16 + 7 x^8 + 1 > = < x + 7747110435841547256507133, 11529190147322608601758016 >

real    0m2.037s
user    0m2.034s
sys     0m0.000s
daniel@frobnitz:~/git/groebner-zx/builddir$ time ./groebner_test
Running main() from /build/googletest-qXr8Ln/googletest-1.10.0/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 11 tests from 2 test suites.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 3 tests from Buchberger
[ RUN      ] Buchberger.IdealSetOrdering
[       OK ] Buchberger.IdealSetOrdering (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Buchberger.ReduceMod
[       OK ] Buchberger.ReduceMod (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Buchberger.Buchberger
[       OK ] Buchberger.Buchberger (16547 ms)
[----------] 3 tests from Buchberger (16547 ms total)

[----------] 8 tests from Polynomial
[ RUN      ] Polynomial.Equality
[       OK ] Polynomial.Equality (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Polynomial.Degree
[       OK ] Polynomial.Degree (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Polynomial.Coefficient
[       OK ] Polynomial.Coefficient (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Polynomial.Negate
[       OK ] Polynomial.Negate (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Polynomial.TimesXTo
[       OK ] Polynomial.TimesXTo (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Polynomial.ScalarMult
[       OK ] Polynomial.ScalarMult (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Polynomial.Subtract
[       OK ] Polynomial.Subtract (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Polynomial.ToString
[       OK ] Polynomial.ToString (0 ms)
[----------] 8 tests from Polynomial (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 11 tests from 2 test suites ran. (16547 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 11 tests.

real    0m16.548s
user    0m16.499s
sys     0m0.000s
```

(Without that test case added into `Buchberger.Buchberger` the test suite takes a low enough time that it reports 0 ms total.)

As a wild guess, maybe does googletest enable malloc debugging or something along those lines?  The code, as it currently stands, isn't really optimized and probably makes a lot of copies of vectors and `mpz` objects, and thus a lot of memory allocations and deallocations.

Here are the relevant source files, cut down a bit:

polynomial.h

```
#pragma once

#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using Z = mpz_class;
inline Z operator""_Z(const char* s) {
  return operator""_mpz(s);
}

class polynomial {
public:
  polynomial();
  polynomial(std::initializer_list<Z> coeffs);
  explicit polynomial(std::vector<Z> coeffs);

  int degree() const;
  Z coefficient(int d) const;
  const std::vector<Z>& coefficients() const;

  void negate();
  polynomial times_x_to(int n) const;
  polynomial& operator-=(const polynomial& other);
  polynomial& operator*=(Z n);

  std::string to_string() const;

private:
  std::vector<Z> m_coeffs;

  void normalize();
  static std::string monomial_to_string(const Z& coeff, int d);
};

bool operator==(const polynomial& p, const polynomial& q);
bool operator!=(const polynomial& p, const polynomial& q);

polynomial operator-(const polynomial& p);
polynomial operator-(const polynomial& p, const polynomial& q);
polynomial operator*(Z n, const polynomial& p);
```

polynomial.cpp

```
#include "polynomial.h"
#include <algorithm>

polynomial::polynomial() { }
polynomial::polynomial(std::initializer_list<Z> coeffs) : m_coeffs(coeffs)
{
  normalize();
}

polynomial::polynomial(std::vector<Z> coeffs) : m_coeffs(std::move(coeffs))
{
  normalize();
}

void polynomial::normalize() {
  auto first_nonzero = find_if(m_coeffs.begin(), m_coeffs.end(),
                   [](const Z& coeff) { return coeff != 0; });
  m_coeffs.erase(m_coeffs.begin(), first_nonzero);
}

int polynomial::degree() const {
  return m_coeffs.size() - 1;
}

Z polynomial::coefficient(int d) const {
  if (d > degree())
    return 0;
  return m_coeffs[degree() - d];
}

const std::vector<Z>& polynomial::coefficients() const {
  return m_coeffs;
}

void polynomial::negate() {
  for (auto& coeff : m_coeffs)
    coeff = -coeff;
}

polynomial polynomial::times_x_to(int n) const {
  if (m_coeffs.empty())
    return *this;
  auto result_coeffs = m_coeffs;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    result_coeffs.push_back(0);
  return polynomial{result_coeffs};
}

polynomial& polynomial::operator-=(const polynomial& other) {
  while (other.m_coeffs.size() > this->m_coeffs.size())
    m_coeffs.insert(m_coeffs.begin(), 0);
  auto i = m_coeffs.begin() + (this->m_coeffs.size() - other.m_coeffs.size());
  for (const auto& other_coeff : other.m_coeffs) {
    *i -= other_coeff;
    ++i;
  }
  normalize();
  return *this;
}

polynomial& polynomial::operator*=(Z n) {
  if (n == 0)
    m_coeffs.clear();
  else {
    for (Z& coeff : m_coeffs)
      coeff *= n;
  }
  return *this;
}

bool operator==(const polynomial& p, const polynomial& q) {
  return p.coefficients() == q.coefficients();
}
bool operator!=(const polynomial& p, const polynomial& q) {
  return !(p == q);
}

polynomial operator-(const polynomial& p) {
  polynomial result = p;
  result.negate();
  return result;
}

polynomial operator-(const polynomial& p, const polynomial& q) {
  polynomial result = p;
  result -= q;
  return result;
}

polynomial operator*(Z n, const polynomial& p) {
  polynomial result = p;
  result *= n;
  return result;
}

std::string polynomial::monomial_to_string(const Z& coeff, int d) {
  std::string result;
  if (coeff == 1 && d > 0)
    result = "";
  else if (coeff == -1 && d > 0)
    result = "-";
  else {
    result = coeff.get_str();
    if (d > 0)
      result += " ";
  }
  if (d == 1)
    result += "x";
  else if (d > 1) {
    result += "x^";
    result += std::to_string(d);
  }
  return result;
}
  
std::string polynomial::to_string() const {
  if (m_coeffs.empty())
    return "0";
  std::string result = monomial_to_string(m_coeffs.front(), degree());
  for (int d = degree() - 1; d >= 0; --d) {
    auto coeff = coefficient(d);
    if (coeff > 0) {
      result += " + ";
      result += monomial_to_string(coeff, d);
    }
    else if (coeff < 0) {
      result += " - ";
      result += monomial_to_string(-coeff, d);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

buchberger.h

```
#pragma once

#include <set>
#include "polynomial.h"

struct decreasing_leading_term {
  bool operator()(const polynomial& p, const polynomial& q) const;
};

using ideal_basis = std::set<polynomial, decreasing_leading_term>;

void buchberger(ideal_basis& b);
```

buchberger.cpp

```
#include "buchberger.h"
#include <algorithm>

bool decreasing_leading_term::operator()(const polynomial& p, const polynomial& q) const {
  const auto& p_coeffs = p.coefficients();
  const auto& q_coeffs = q.coefficients();
  if (p_coeffs.size() > q_coeffs.size())
    return true;
  else if (p_coeffs.size() < q_coeffs.size())
    return false;
  else if (p_coeffs.empty())
    return false;
  else if (p_coeffs.front() > q_coeffs.front())
    return true;
  else if (p_coeffs.front() < q_coeffs.front())
    return false;
  else return p_coeffs > q_coeffs;
}

void reduce_mod(polynomial& p, const polynomial& q) {
  int q_deg = q.degree();
  if (q_deg < 0)
    return;
  Z q_leading_coeff = q.coefficient(q_deg);

  int initial_p_deg = p.degree();
  for (int i = initial_p_deg - q_deg; i >= 0; --i) {
    Z p_coeff = p.coefficient(i + q_deg);
    Z quotient = p_coeff / q_leading_coeff;
    if (p_coeff - quotient * q_leading_coeff < 0)
      --quotient;
    p -= quotient * q.times_x_to(i);
  }
}

bool buchberger_search(ideal_basis& b) {
  for (auto i = b.begin(); i != b.end(); ++i) {
    auto p = *i;
    for (auto j = std::next(i); j != b.end(); ++j) {
      reduce_mod(p, *j);
    }
    if (p != *i) {
      if (p.coefficients().front() < 0)
    p = -p;
      b.erase(i);
      if (p != polynomial{})
    b.insert(p);
      return true;
    }
  }

  for (auto i = b.begin(); i != b.end(); ++i) {
    for (auto j = std::next(i); j != b.end(); ++j) {
      auto p = j->times_x_to(i->degree() - j->degree());
      for (auto k = i; k != b.end(); ++k)
    reduce_mod(p, *k);
      if (p != polynomial{}) {
    if (p.coefficients().front() < 0)
      p = -p;
    b.insert(p);
    return true;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}
  
void buchberger(ideal_basis& b) {
  b.erase(polynomial{});

  while (true) {
    auto i = std::find_if(b.begin(), b.end(), [](const polynomial& p) { return p.coefficients().front() < 0; });
    if (i == b.end())
      break;
    auto minus_p = -(*i);
    b.erase(i);
    b.insert(minus_p);
  }

  while (buchberger_search(b))
    ;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "polynomial.h"
#include "buchberger.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <experimental/iterator>

int main() {
  std::string line;
  std::vector<polynomial> v;
  while (std::getline(std::cin, line) && !line.empty()) {
    std::istringstream iss { line };
    polynomial p { std::vector<Z> { std::istream_iterator<Z>{iss},
                    std::istream_iterator<Z>{} }};
    v.push_back(std::move(p));
  }

  std::cout << "< ";
  std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(),
         std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, ", "),
         [](const polynomial& p) { return p.to_string(); });
  std::cout << " > = < " << std::flush;

  ideal_basis b { v.begin(), v.end() };
  buchberger(b);
  std::transform(b.begin(), b.end(),
         std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, ", "),
         [](const polynomial& p) { return p.to_string(); });
  std::cout << " >\n";

  return 0;
}
```

buchberger_test.cpp

```
#include "buchberger.h"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

ideal_basis buchberger_of(const ideal_basis& b) {
  ideal_basis result = b;
  buchberger(result);
  return result;
}

TEST(Buchberger, Buchberger) {
  EXPECT_EQ(buchberger_of({ {1, 0, 0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, -3, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {3, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1} }),
            (ideal_basis{ {1, 7747110435841547256507133_Z},
              {11529190147322608601758016_Z} }));
}
```

meson.build build driver

```
project('groebner', 'cpp')
gmpxxdep = dependency('gmpxx')
groebner_lib = static_library('groebnerlib',
                  'buchberger.cpp',
                  'polynomial.cpp',
                  dependencies : gmpxxdep)
executable('groebner', 'main.cpp', link_with : groebner_lib, install : true)

gtestdep = dependency('gtest_main')
testexe = executable('groebner_test',
             'buchberger_test.cpp',
             link_with : groebner_lib,
             dependencies : gtestdep)
test('groebner_test', testexe)
```

groebner_test_case.txt input

```
1 0 0 5 3 0 0 0 0 0 9 0 0 -3 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 1 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

build commands used for test:

```
meson builddir -Dbuildtype=release
cd builddir
meson compile
time ./groebner < ../groebner_test_case.txt
time ./groebner_test
```

(The full original code which shows this difference is up at https://github.com/dschepler/groebner-zx in case looking at that might help.)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] without relying on external links. Are both executables compiled with the same optimisation levels?

Comment: Not only same optimization levels, the bulk of the code is in the same object files linked into both executables.  I'll see what I can do about a minimal example, though I'm not sure what I could cut out other than the other unit tests - what I wrote was already pretty much the minimum needed to get the algorithm running.

Comment: I don't see any code or build files in your post at all so is definitely not a [mre]

Comment: OK, I've added a minimal example now.